# Why does rails app return 406 instead of 404 in some cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

I have a huge Rails app that is running quit well but I have a problem with google because of some nasty behavior of the app. When I call

http://railsapp.com/index.html

Which doesnt exist the app returns an 404 error which is correct. But when I call

http://railsapp.com/index.htm

It returns an 406 error wich isnt that great. This problem appears every time a non existing file with .htm extension is requested. How can I make my rails app return 404 instead of 406?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 respond_to do |format|    
   format.html {}
   format.js {}        
  end
```

because in your "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/.." 406.htm file is not their so that it gives error and 404.html file is available in public folder so that it's call.

in your {RAILS_ROOT}/public these are the file is their

```
1. 404.html
2. 422.html
3. 500.html
```

if you use these file then it call else it will give error like file does not exist.

or

you can also do this In the ApplicationController define a method like:

```
def render_404
  render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html",  :status => 404
end
```

Answer (score 1):

406.htm file is not available in your public folder so that you get error -non existing file. Add 406.html file in your public folder as per your layout and then try.